# Why is my code outputting random numbers even though they are just counts?

Tags: c, output

I am starting to learn c. I am trying to make a code that will count the amount of a's and A's in a sentence but the code gives me random numbers every time it is executed even if it is the same sentence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char words[10000000000];
    int i;
    int acount = 0;
    int Acount = 0;
    char A[0]="A";
    char a[0]="a";
    printf("Input your sentence to be counted.");
    scanf("%s",words);
    printf("%s",words);
    for (i=0;i<=sizeof(words);i++)
    {
        if (words[i]==a[0]){
            acount++;
        }else if (words[i]==A[0]){
            Acount++;
        }
    }
    printf ("\nThe number of A's is %i. The number of a's is %i.",Acount,acount);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Just a heads-up - that array will try to allocate 10GB of memory (perhaps overkill for this case). In other news, provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to let us better help you.

Comment: `char A[0]="A";` is an error. That shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @hnefatl of the stack (it is the auto one)

Comment: What's your OS? Because I don't know any OS that allows that much stack by default.

Comment: @melpomene it will compile with the warning.

Comment: Also two variables with the same name but different capitalisation is bad

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: try [this](https://ideone.com/G3dtrA)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is my code outputting random numbers even though they are just
>   counts?

Because you're counting *uninitialized* memory, given the code you posted.

This is uninitialized:

```
char words[10000000000];
```

(If 10 GB fits....)

This only sets the memory in `words` for the string that's read, plus the terminating `'\0'` character:

```
scanf("%s",words);
```

Assuming it works, anyway.  You don't check the return value, so maybe it didn't work...

Now what will this loop do? (Ignoring the fact that `int` likely isn't big enough to index a 10GB array...)

```
for (i=0;i<=sizeof(words);i++)
{
    if (words[i]==a[0]){
        acount++;
    }else if (words[i]==A[0]){
        Acount++;
    }
}
```

That loop will check *every* `char` in the array `word` and compare it to either 'A' or 'a'.  Every last 10 *billion* or so of them, many if not most of them likely containing unknown values.

It will also check one `char` *past* the end of `word`.  That's not good.  This will not check past the end of `word`:

```
size_t i;
 ...
for (i=0;i<sizeof(words);i++)
{
    if (words[i]==a[0]){
        acount++;
    }else if (words[i]==A[0]){
        Acount++;
    }
}
```

Note the change to `<` instead of `<=`, and the use of `size_t` for `i` instead of `int`.

Even better, so you don't try counting random data:

```
size_t i;
 ...
for (i = 0; words[i]; i++) {
    if (words[i] == a[0]) {
        acount++;
    } else if (words[i] == A[0]) {
        Acount++;
    }
}
```

Since a string ends in a `'\0'` `char` value, the loop will now end when `words[i]` has a zero value.

Comment: `i<sizeof(words)` --> `words[i] != '\0'`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks.  Getting to that...  ;-)

Comment: To add to BLUEPIXY's comment, `sizeof(words)` is still wrong because it will read past the last initialized byte which after `scanf()` we hope has `'\0'` as a value.

Comment: Not going to mention this: "char A[0]="A";
    char a[0]="a";" ?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Yes.  But I left that there becase that answers the question *why* he's seeing random output values - he's counting random data.

Comment: @savram *Not going to mention this: "char A[0]="A"; char a[0]="a";" ?*  I view that as a code error that's not really relevant as to *why* random output counts are generated.  Yes, it's *wrong* and needs to be fixed, and it is UB, but even as UB it's not likely to cause the results he's seeing. "Nasal demons", while possible, aren't likely...